# Split Method: returning different parts

Tags: javascript, methods, split

What I want to do is have my leap year function return only the year value when the user enters a date in the form of MM/DD/YYYY. Right now, I have it working with just a year, but I want the function to require the user to enter a date in that form and calculate if it's a leap year or not. How do I modify my current code to do this. I've declared a new variable with the split method. Thanks!

```
function isLeaper() {
            var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
            var splitYear = year.split ('/');
            // 1. If the year is divisible by 4, but not 100.
            if ((parseInt(splitYear) % 4) == 0) {
                if (parseInt(splitYear) % 100 == 0) {
                    if (parseInt(splitYear) % 400 != 0) {
                        alert(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!');
                        return "false";
                    }
                    if (parseInt(splitYear) % 400 == 0) {
                        alert(year + 'is a leap year. Hooray!');
                        return "true";
                    }
                }
                if (parseInt(splitYear) % 100 != 0) {
                    alert(year + 'is a leap year. Hooray!');
                        return "true";
                }
            }
            if ((parseInt(splitYear) % 4) != 0) {
                alert(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!');
                        return "false";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(splitYear)` and you may find out.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
var splitYear = year.split ('/');
```

to

```
var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
var arr = year.split('/');
var splitYear = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

This will get the year if the variable `year` is in the form of MM/DD/YYYY and YYYY.

You can try this:

```
$('#yourContainerID').html(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!').fadeIn('normal',function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

For more information, see [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)  and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Comment: That worked great! Thank you for your help. I knew I was almost there, but I was missing the part on how to return the split. Thanks again!!

Comment: Also, right now, the anser is displayed in an alert. Do you know how to use a JQuery reveal and slow fade out to display the answer instead of the alert? I have no idea how to use JQuery.

Comment: @AlanJosephSylvestre please check my post.

Comment: Great! But, what do I put in for the container id? The id of a div tag?

Comment: @AlanJosephSylvestre yes, the div your want put your message in.